# Can I marry in Skyrim on PS3?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've tried many times and completed the companion quest and mara quest and got the amulet of mara and still can't marry Aela or anyone else. I'm a Dragonborn in the game.

Comment: Have you equipped the amulet?

Answer (score 3):

Find Maramal in the Temple of Mara, in Riften, and ask to be enlightened about Mara, the Goddess of Love and about marriage in Skyrim. Push the query further to receive the option to purchase the Amulet of Mara from him for 200 gold.

***Note:***
You can't get married without talking to Maramal